# How to output JSON in python so it can be used for Geckoboard's Highcharts plugin

Tags: python, json, formatting, highcharts

I feel like there's a reasonably simple solution out there for my problem.

I'm doing some data manipulation that at the end point gets printed out in a format for [highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com).  Currently I'm pulling the whole set of nested dictionaries apart and printing each part out, but I was hoping there was something like JSON.dumps(dict) where the output was formatted with all keys unquoted. So, in code-ish-stuff:

```
{
    'chart': {'backgroundColor': 'Blue',
              'borderColor': 'Black',
              'renderTo': 'container'},
    'xAxis': { ... },
...
}
```

Outputs to

```
{
    chart: {
        backgroundColor: 'Blue',
        borderColor: 'Black',
        renderTo: 'container'},
    xAxis: { ... },
...
}
```

If I can't do outputting like this is there a good way to interface with HighCharts from python?  I haven't really ran across one yet, despite some reasonable Google-Fu.

EDIT: I'm working on making this compatible with the [Geckoboard - Highcharts plugin](http://docs.geckoboard.com/custom-widgets/highchart.html) where-in I don't get the access to the full ability of javascript for parsing the output.  I need to have it already formatted and ready to roll when I send the data out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just provide the valid json text. Examples in your question are not valid json. Using [Push API](http://docs.geckoboard.com/custom-widgets/push.html):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import urllib2

try:
    r = urllib2.urlopen("https://push.geckoboard.com/v1/send/" + widget_key,
                        json.dumps(nested_dict))
except IOError as e:
    if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
       print "connection error:", e.reason
    elif hasattr(e, 'code'):
       print "http error:", e.code
       print e.read()
    else:
       print "error:", e
else: # success
    assert json.load(r)["success"]
```

Comment: This is close, and I figure I'm just going to need to ride them to get highcharts added to their push dataset.  This is going to be the closest one to what I want it looks like.

Comment: @JeffLangemeier: the same applies to [the polling api](http://docs.geckoboard.com/custom-widgets/polling.html): just provide a valid json. You could use [`flask`](http://flask.pocoo.org/), [`bottle`](http://bottlepy.org), etc to generate json dynamically in response to Geckoboard's http requests (or you could generate a static json file periodically (python + cron) and serve it using any web-server).

Comment: You sir are a scholar and a saint.  This cleared up everything perfectly.

Comment: Jeff, I'm having this same issue, except this solution doesn't seem to be working for me. Any chance you could post your code?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You've got to decode the string on client-side (with javascript):

```
JSON.parse('{"background": "black"}')
```

This method will return you javascript object which you can pass to Highcharts.

So you need to save your python output to js string and then convert it to JS-object.

Comment: I like this solution, if I had access to JSON.parse() it would be perfect, but, as it stands I don't.  See Edit for clarity.

Comment: JSON should always be with quotes (otherwise it is not valid and will not work in any valid JSON decoder including javascript `JSON` and python `json` and `simplejson`). Can you explain why you can't use javascript to parse the output when you have access to create javascript objects?

Comment: @JeffLangemeier since you are using highcharts, there is a high chance you have jQuery available too, `$.parseJSON()` does similar job @ http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: @Jugal Not on my end.  I'm having to deal with a large amount of backend data that is being curated with python, and I know well enough how to setup a string to deal with that, but I'm using an outside system for highcharts such that, I don't have access to how they're handling it.  Geckoboard wants just the object itself essentially, so I'm trying to format it as the object w/o having to add another language (jscript) on top of the python already being used.